# React: Intersection Observer Is not updating states

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, intersection-observer

Goal is to make kind of an infinite scroll with intersection observer where whenever user scrolls to the bottom, new things appears. Now the original code is too long so here is a simplified version of it:

```
function App() {
  const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  const [ProductIds, setProductIds] = useState<number[]>([])
  const loaderRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      const loader = entries[0];
      if (loader.isIntersecting) {
        updateProductIds()
      }
    });
  
    if (loaderRef.current) {
      observer.observe(loaderRef.current);
    }
  
    return () => {
      if (loaderRef.current) {
        observer.unobserve(loaderRef.current);
      }
    }
  }, [])
  

  function updateProductIds () {
    let newId = ids[ProductIds.length]
    if (newId) {
      setProductIds(prev => ([...prev, newId]))
    }
  }
   
  return (
    <>
      {ProductIds.map((id: number) => (
        <div key={id} className="h-96 m-4 bg-green-900 text-white text-xl">
          {`Product ${id}`}
        </div>
      ))}

      <div
        ref={loaderRef} 
        className={`h-10 text-xl bg-gray-700 text-white`}
      >
        Loader
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Expected Output: A list of div elements with Product 1, Product 2, Product 3 .... Product 6 as inner texts

Actual Output: Product 1, Product 1, Product 1, Product 1, Product 1, Product 1

But when I do it this way, it works fine !!

```
useEffect(() => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    const loader = entries[0];
    if (loader.isIntersecting) {
      setProductIds(prev => ([...prev, ids[idRef.current]]))
      idRef.current++
    }
  });
  
  if (loaderRef.current) {
    observer.observe(loaderRef.current);
  }
  
  return () => {
    if (loaderRef.current) {
      observer.unobserve(loaderRef.current);
    }
  }
}, [])
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little more please. I didn't got it !! when i console log, it does logs values (although the same value ie "1" is added to ProductIds), so i assumed that it does triggers intersectionObserver !!. Please tell me a little bit more. What exactly should i change here ??

Comment: I did not figure out where is the issue with your code, but there is the similiar usage https://github.com/RedDwarfTech/texhub-web/blob/main/src/component/common/previewer/doc/MemoizedPDFPreview.tsx, to use IntersectionObserver to detect the current pdf page number. Maybe give you some clue to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

## Snippet 1

The issue in the first snippet is that of a stale closure over the `ProductIds` state in the `updateProductIds` callback in the `observer` handler, where the observer gets only a single copy of when the component mounts and the `useEffect` hook runs at the end of the initial render cycle. Since the `ProductsIds` state reference never updates in the callback, it is always the initial empty array, and since it's empty `ProductIds.length` is always `0`, and so the first element from the `ids` array, e.g. `ids[0]` or `1`, is the `newId` value, and since it's truthy the `ProductsIds` state is updated to append `1` to the state each time, hence the resultant "Product 1, Product 1, Product 1, Product 1, Product 1, Product 1".

```js
function updateProductIds () {
  let newId = ids[ProductIds.length]; // <-- ProductIds always []

  if (newId) {
    setProductIds(prev => ([...prev, newId]));
  }
}
```

You could fix this by checking the array length in the state updater callback so it can always reference the current `ProductIds` value.

```js
function updateProductIds () {
  setProductIds(ProductIds => {
      const newId = ids[ProductIds.length];

      if (newId) {
        // Return updated state
        return ProductIds.concat(newId);
      } else {
        // Return current state, no change
        return ProductIds;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

## Snippet 2

The second implementation works because you are skirting the closure issue by using a separate React ref that you manually increment each time.

Assuming all the `ids` are basically 1-indexed, you can simply use the `ProductIds` array length to compute the next product id value. When `ProductIds` is empty the length is 0 and so the first product id is `ids[0]` or 1, when `ProductIds` is `[1]` the length is 1 and so the second product id is `ids[1]` or 2, and so on.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([{ isIntersecting }]) => {
    if (isIntersecting) {
      setProductIds(ProductIds => {
        if (ids[ProductIds.length]) {
          return ProductIds.concat(ids[ProductIds.length]);
        } else {
          return ProductIds;
        }
      });
    }
  });
  
  if (loaderRef.current) {
    observer.observe(loaderRef.current);
  }
  
  return () => {
    if (loaderRef.current) {
      observer.unobserve(loaderRef.current);
    }
  }
}, []);
```